# Are atomic operations on non-atomic types in C atomic?

Tags: c, atomic

The C17 standard specifies a list of atomic operations. For example, an atomic read-write-modify operation on an atomic object of type `A` is defined in the standard as:

```
C atomic_fetch_add(volatile A *object, M operand);
```

But we can call `atomic_fetch_add` on non-atomic types:

```
static int x;
static int foo(void *arg) {
  atomic_fetch_add(&x, 3);
}
```

My question: is the above `atomic_fetch_add` operation on the non-atomic object `x` guaranteed to be atomic?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> on an atomic object of type A is defined in the standard
>
> But we can call

GCC will accept it. But on clang you'll get an error.

> is the above atomic_fetch_add operation on the non-atomic object x guaranteed to be atomic?

No. In the standard the behavior of the code you presented is not defined, there is no guarantee of any kind. From [https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.17](https://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.17) :

> 5 In the following synopses:
>
> - An A refers to one of the atomic types. [...]

And then all the functions are defined in terms of `A`, like in [https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.17.7.5p2](https://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.17.7.5p2) :

`C atomic_fetch_key(volatile A *object, M operand);`

[Atomic type](https://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.2.4) is a type with `_Atomic`.